# Logging levels in C#

Tags: logging

```
public class Logger
{
    private string logFilePath;
    string log_file_name = null;
    string folderPath = null;

    public Logger(string logFileName)
    {
        log_file_name = logFileName;
        folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        logFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, logFileName);
    }

    public void LogInformation(string message)
    {
        string logLevel = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["infoLogLevel"];
        string logEntry = $"[{logLevel}] - Date {DateTime.Now}\n{message}";
        File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, logEntry + Environment.NewLine);
    }
} I am trying to log to a txt file based on different log levels. I have created the LogInformation, but I want to configure the loglevel to trace and error so that trace messages and errors are logged as well. I am new to logging and I am not sure how to implement that logic.
```

I tried to create another LogTrace method with a different logging format. The methods should have a different purpose according to their log level